# Why am I being asked to suggest friends for someone who is not a Facebook friend?

Tags: facebook

I was notified that an ex of mine had just joined Facebook and asked to suggest friends for him. His profile has absolutely *no* info on it or photos etc. We are not Facebook friends and my phone no. is different to what is was then when we were together. His emails - only a very few sent back in 2009 - have long been deleted too, though my email address is he same.

If I were to message him, it would go straight to his inbox without having to pay - it should go to Other if we are not friends. 
Has Facebook informed me of his joining because he has looked at my profile? I can't think of any other reason.

Answer (score 3):

You used Facebook invite via email feature sometime in the past and you probably don't remember his email being part of that invite list.

You can check your invited contacts here https://www.facebook.com/invite_history.php

And choose to remove it here https://www.facebook.com/contact_importer/remove_uploads.php